Time in a world that is closer to their Sun
Setting: It is millions of years in the future and the sun has expanded, making it closer to Earth. The human species has survived but lives in a very different world. Think something like Mars, but there are still some water sources and desert plants/animals.
What would time be like in this version of Earth? The earth moves faster, so are days shorter? Should there still be seasons? Does the sun still set?

Why do you believe the earth would move faster?

The Earth is closer to the surface of the sun but not to its center. The total mechanical energy is conserved over the course of the Sun's expansion, so the orbital speed remains constant.

How many planets are there "like Mars" in this solar system? If it's a different solar system, then please add many, many more details about what it is you're trying to achieve. (Mass/type of star, planet). If you don't know what to ask, try the search at the top of the page for ideas as to context, eg. using the search term habitable zone. Maybe look at how orbital periods work too.

For future reference: you are allowed one and only one question per post. You're asking at least four. Please carefully read [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand the limits of this site. Thanks.

The earth will not move faster. The distance to surface of the central body will never matter; only the distance to the center. The gravity Earth experiences from the sun will be the same, so the orbital period and tangential velocity will be the same as they are now.
There will of course still be seasons, unless the Earth's axial tilt has changed. It will overall be much hotter, and the atmosphere might not exist anymore, but there will still be seasons.
The sun will, of course, set unless the Earth becomes tidally locked. So long as the Earth rotates with a day-period not equal to its orbital period.
Time would flow at approximately the same rate, for all intents and purposes, but I doubt there would be anyone left on Earth to notice any changes anyway...
